# Orientability issue when classifying symplectic structures on compact orientable surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, volume, symplectic-geometry, orientation

I have seen [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448761/are-there-exotic-symplectic-structures-on-s2), where they identify symplectic structures on a compact orientable surface with $\mathbb R\smallsetminus0$, which I understand except for one issue regarding the orientation on $\Sigma$.

Let $\Sigma$ be a closed orientable surface surface, and let $\omega$ and $\omega'$ be symplectic forms on $\Sigma$. Then each $\omega$ and $\omega'$ determines an orientation on $\Sigma$, and so any diffeomorphism such that $F^*\omega'=\omega$ preserves orientation. However, suppose that $\omega$ and $\omega'$ induce different orientations, then $F:\Sigma\rightarrow \Sigma$ is still an orientation preserving map, but I feel like the claim that $[\omega]=[\omega']$ no longer holds. In particular if we denote by $\Sigma$ the surface with the orientation induced by $\omega$, and $\Sigma'$ the surface with the orientation induced by $\omega'$, then it is true that:
$$\int_\Sigma \omega=\int_{\Sigma'}\omega'$$
however, if the orientations disagree then:
$$\int_\Sigma\omega'=-\int_\Sigma \omega$$
so $[\omega]=-[\omega']$ in $H^2(\mathbb R)$. In particular, if $\Sigma=\mathbb S^2$, there is an antipodal map $t$, so there exists an example of this form with $(\mathbb S^2,\omega)$ and $(\mathbb S^2,-\omega)$.

Moreover, having read Moser's original paper, he proves his general statement (Moser's theorem) on a closed manifold $M$ for orientation preserving automorphisms, which I assume means a fixed orientation on $M$, as if he doesn't Moser's trick completely falls apart. So I am unsure of how to reconcile this difference in the other direction...

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that each oriented surface admits an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Do I know this because of some elementary result from differential topology, or because I know the harder result that every orientable closed surface is either a sphere, a connected sum of tori, or a connected sum of $\mathbb{RP}^2$?

Comment: You need the classification of surfaces for this,  which is an elementary result comparing to Moser's theorem. BTW, a connected sum of projective planes is never orientable.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Also, would this imply that the symplectic structures are in bijection with $\mathbb R^+$ and not $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Of course. $R$ does not even make sense.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I meant $\mathbb R-0$ like the linked post says. I think the classification of surfaces is harder (longer at least) than Moser's theorem, but maybe that's just a personal opinion.

Comment: Yes, the total area is the complete invariant, where the total area is computed with respect to the orientation defined via the area form. As for the classification of surfaces: I learned the PL proof before I got to college and before I knew what a differential form is. In the smooth category, the proof is not much harder.

Comment: @MoisheKohan but this seems to imply that symplectic structures up to diffeomorphism are those which satisfy $[\omega]=\pm[\omega']$

Comment: I do not understand your last comment.

Comment: I start to see what you mean, Chris. I now would agree that the linked post was wrong. The symplectic forms on an orientable surface are isomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^*$, but up do diffeomorphism, they are isomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^+$.